# Space transport systems

Tags: spacecraft

For a space school space project, I was assigned of tinkering around space transport systems, which can also include mass drivers, space guns, space rail guns, space tugs with spacecraft systems. The system needs to be reliable and must be designed for deeps space missions till Jupiter carrying humans or cargo. The only such spacecraft which I found was the starship proposed by Space X which is still under development. Can somebody suggest more ideas..

Comment: Hi, welcome to space stack exchange. As written your question is not a good fit here. Please edit it to focus on a single question, open-ended "what do you think" questions are explicitly not allowed. Please refer to the help pages here https://space.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on WorldBuilding SE.

Comment: Nothing currently comes close, not even Starship, so you must reach more into the sci-fi realm. Some concepts closer to reality may include [muon-catalyzed fusion drive](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24205/), [centrifugal habitats](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32072/), [Project Orion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/886), [hydroponics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6344), [MOXIE](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/51645), [NTR](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ntr), [shielding](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22056/103)